# why do typescript interface functions not have a function name?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

It seems to define the interface for a function, you just declare the function signature, eg the parameters, but not the func name.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types

> To describe a function type with an interface, we give the interface a call signature. This is like a function declaration with only the parameter list and return type given. Each parameter in the parameter list requires both name and type.

So, kind of like an anonymous function?

This seems odd as later if I compile ANY function with the same params, it will pass?

I'm trying to write typings for someone else's library and starting off with `any`

```
interface ISlackEvent {
  ack?: any   // function
}
```

which is called as just `event.ack()`

how would I type this more clearly as a function?

```
interface ISlackEvent {
  (): void
```

seems to not give me much guard rails, however this also works:

```
interface ISlackEvent {
  ack?(): void
```

So not clear if i'm misreading the docs, if I should NOT give the function a name in the interface?

Comment: It's for when the interfaces implementation *is* a function instead of having a function.

Comment: Your interface isn’t a function, so the documentation on function types doesn’t apply.